# Putty SSH client key exchange fails after upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: upgrade, ssh, putty

I am unable to connect to my Ubuntu server with Putty 0.62 after upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04. PuTTY Fatal error:

```
Couldn't agree a key exchange algorithm (available: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffe-hellman-group16sha512,diffie-hellman-group18,sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256)
```

The matching message in /var/log/auth.log is:

```
sshd[5210]: Unable to negotiate with 192.168.1.20 port 533 07: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group-exc hange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diff ie-hellman-group1-sha1,rsa2048-sha256,rsa1024-sha1 [preauth]
```

Answer (score 2):

Searching around I found post claiming that "Ubuntu 20.04 has disabled the SHA1-based key exchange methods after some attacks have been found on SHA1." Direct ssh commands from the Ubuntu would work around this by re-enabling diffie-hellman-group1-sha1. A putty specific post suggested pushing diffie-hellman options to the bottom of the list in PuTTY's Connection > SSH > Kex preferences, but that would just leave me with RSA which also seemed to be refused.

For me the fix was to upgrade from PuTTY 0.62 to 0.76. This added ECDH key exchange to the top of the list in PuTTY and ssh to the Ubuntu 20.04 server worked.

Comment: exactly my issue, thanks a lot. I noticed that putty 0.62 was installed in c:\program files (x86) and putty 0.78 was installed in c:\programmes, so my batch scripts doesn't worked. I copied new putty.exe and pscp.exe in old folder and my scripts works fine.